# compile java file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

hello i am new in eclipse,i have one web project in which java file and jsp file are there.  all connection string and database query written in java file and all html code written in jsp file. when i change in jsp file i get result but when i change in java file i cant get result... i know after change in java file i have to compile whole file... but i want to know how to compile java after change in  eclipse.In my "src" folder i put all java file and in web content folder i put all jsp file.. know please tell me how to compile and get change.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you have "Build Automatically" checked, Eclipse will compile Java files automatically. Now whenever you made changes to Java file, just you need to re-build and run the application on server that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project -> Build All.
Or check 'Build Automatically' option under project menu.

Comment: i have try this ... but i cant get effect

Comment: Please check whether the classes are generated in the classes folder under WEB-INF. Delete the classes folder, Clean the project (Project -> Clean) and then build.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, go to **[Project_Directory]/build**. Delete all compiled classes.
Now Go to **Project -->> Build All**.
I hope it will work for you.